# Studio mic --> Headphone jack not working

Tags: microphone, cable+, transformers, powering

I have created a system to plug my studio mic (MXL 990) into my MacBook's 3.5mm headphone jack that consists of the following system: 
 Mic -> AC Power supply for the mic -> 3-Prong microphone cable to 6mm headphone jack transformer -> 6mm to 3.5mm converter.
 The system, however, doesn't work. I have tried diagnosing the problem myself with the following:

- Using a different mic
- Skipping the transformer in the line
- Skipping the AC Power supply in the line
- Hooking up to a different mac, and directly to a speaker.
- Checking the output voltage of the AC power supply

[image: Mic -> 3-prong mic cable (1)]

[image: 3-prong mic cable (1) -> AC Power supply to mic -> 3-prong mic calbe (2)]

[image: 3-prong mic Cable (2) -> Transformer -> 6mm jack -> 3.5mm jack -> Computer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suspect area is the ¼" jack &  ¼" - ⅛" adaptor.
It needs to be correctly wired as a mic input to that specific jack socket, which on a Mac is a 4-pole connector, TRRS, for headset/mic combos.

I can't see the whole TR[R]S to be able to guess, but even if it is correct, the mono Shure TS jack is going to be shorting the connections inside the ⅛" adaptor.

You would be far better served if you invested in a dedicated USB audio interface.